# if else statement in AngularJS templates

Tags: if-statement, angularjs

I want to do a condition in an AngularJS template. I fetch a video list from the Youtube API. Some of the videos are in 16:9 ratio and some are in 4:3 ratio.

I want to make a condition like this:

```
if video.yt$aspectRatio equals widescreen then 
    element's attr height="270px"
else
    element's attr height="360px"
```

I'm iterating the videos using `ng-repeat`. Have no idea what should I do for this condition:

- Add a function in the scope?
- Do it in template?

Comment: I found one ng-if articles here. http://goo.gl/wQ30uf

Answer (score 1328, accepted):

Angularjs (versions below 1.1.5) does not provide the `if/else` functionality . Following are a few options to consider for what you want to achieve:

(***Jump to the update below (#5) if you are using version 1.1.5 or greater***)

#### 1. Ternary operator:

As suggested by @Kirk in the comments, the cleanest way of doing this would be to use a ternary operator as follows:

```
<span>{{isLarge ? 'video.large' : 'video.small'}}</span>
```

#### 2. [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive:

can be used something like the following.

```
<div ng-switch on="video">
    <div ng-switch-when="video.large">
        <!-- code to render a large video block-->
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
        <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) / [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives

Alternatively, you might also use `ng-show/ng-hide` but using this will actually render both a large video and a small video element and then hide the one that meets the `ng-hide` condition and shows the one that meets `ng-show` condition. So on each page you'll actually be rendering two different elements.

#### 4. Another option to consider is [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

This can be used as follows.

```
<div ng-class="{large-video: video.large}">
    <!-- video block goes here -->
</div>
```

The above basically will add a `large-video` css class to the div element if `video.large` is truthy.

#### UPDATE: [Angular 1.1.5](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/) introduced the [`ngIf directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

#### 5. [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

In the versions above `1.1.5` you can use the `ng-if` directive. This would remove the element if the expression provided returns `false` and re-inserts the `element` in the DOM if the expression returns `true`. Can be used as follows.

```
<div ng-if="video == video.large">
    <!-- code to render a large video block-->
</div>
<div ng-if="video != video.large">
    <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `ng-switch on="video"` instead `ng-switch-on="video"`

Comment: 3rd option should be `ng-class="{large-video:video.large}"` as per [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass)

Comment: How do that?

    if(){} 
    else if(){} 
    else if(){} 
    else {} 

But include in dom only one element

Comment: Also ternary `<span>{{isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to cart'}}</span>`

Comment: Keep in mind that `ng-if` will NOT add the enclosed elements to the DOM until its condition evaluates to `true`, unlike `ng-hide` and `ng-show`.

Comment: To the comment of Kirk Strobeck, if you have an entity for each record, in my case RuleEntity has method isActive. in view {{rule.isActive() ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play'}}

Comment: Why not simply `ng-switch="video"`? Some problem? or it was not available earlier? For me it it is working quite fine

Comment: @KirkStrobeck I think the ternary should be the **first** option in the answer. The power of ternary made much sense to me now via this example. The other options are cumbersome. Wow!

Comment: Keep in mind that `ng-if` introduces an **isolated scope**, so that `$parent` becomes `$parent.$parent` in the body of `ng-if`.

Comment: Some html minifiers will have trouble with the ternary operator, for example: gulp-minify-html:1.0.4

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of the extra elements do get added to the page, until angular has a chance to clean them up. This could mean you start loading the large video unexpectedly. Try putting this into a block which you don't expect to be rendered: <img src="nothing.jpg" onerror="alert('test');"/>

Comment: Does anyone know about the efficiency of these methods? Is ng-switch easier for the browser to render than 2 ng-ifs?

Answer (score 182):

In the latest version of Angular (as of 1.1.5), they have included a conditional directive called `ngIf`.  It is different from `ngShow` and `ngHide` in that the elements aren't hidden, but not included in the DOM at all.  They are very useful for components which are costly to create but aren't used:

```
<div ng-if="video == video.large">
    <!-- code to render a large video block-->
</div>
<div ng-if="video != video.large">
    <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ng-if` introduces an **isolated scope**, so that `$parent` becomes `$parent.$parent` in the body of `ng-if`.

Answer (score 145):

Ternary is the most clear way of doing this.

```
<div>{{ConditionVar ? 'varIsTrue' : 'varIsFalse'}}</div>
```

Comment: Ho to do this with 2 condition in or?? like <div>{{A==B || A==C ? 'varIsTrue' : 'varIsFalse'}}</div>

Comment: Wrap it (A==B || A==C)

Comment: love this answer! Using ng- directives gives lots of html whitespace if a div doesn't satisfy the condition..

Answer (score 52):

Angular itself doesn't provide if/else functionality, but you can get it by including this module:

https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif

In its own words, it's just "a simple collection of control flow directives: ng-if, ng-else-if, and ng-else."  It's easy and intuitive to use.

Example:

```
<div ng-if="someCondition">
    ...
</div>
<div ng-else-if="someOtherCondition">
    ...
</div>
<div ng-else>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want to repeat the code in div again and again.

Comment: You don't have to repeat anything -- you could as easily do `ng-if="someCondition && someOtherCondition"`. Perhaps I misunderstand? (I wrote that module -- it should work just like `if` and `else` in JS).

Comment: This is an absolute lifesaver. This should be part of Angular core, it's indispensable in template coding. Way cleaner than having ternary operators all over the place, and overcomes the limitations of ng-switch not being able to evaluate expressions.

Comment: Thanks @NicoWesterdale! Also, I added a richer version of ng-switch you might find useful: https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-cases

Answer (score 30):

You could use your `video.yt$aspectRatio` property directly by passing it through a filter, and binding the result to the height attribute in your template.

Your filter would look something like:

```
app.filter('videoHeight', function () {
  return function (input) {
    if (input === 'widescreen') {
      return '270px';
    } else {
      return '360px';
    }
  };
});
```

And the template would be:

```
<video height={{video.yt$aspectRatio | videoHeight}}></video>
```

Comment: How about your code when `video.yt$aspectRatio` is empty or undefined? Is it possible to apply a default value?

Answer (score 13):

In this case you want to "calculate" a pixel value depending of an object property.

I would define a function in the controller that calculates the pixel values.

In the controller:

```
$scope.GetHeight = function(aspect) {
   if(bla bla bla) return 270;
   return 360;
}
```

Then in your template you just write:

```
element height="{{ GetHeight(aspect) }}px "
```

Answer (score 11):

I agree that a **ternary** is extremely clean.   Seems that it is very situational though as somethings I need to display div or p or table , so with a table I don't prefer a ternary for obvious reasons.  Making a call to a function is typically ideal or in my case I did this:

```
<div ng-controller="TopNavCtrl">
        <div ng-if="info.host ==='servername'">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="(group, status) in user.groups">
                    <th style="width: 250px">{{ group }}</th>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.groups[group]" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       <div ng-if="info.host ==='otherservername'">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="(group, status) in user.groups">
                    <th style="width: 250px">{{ group }}</th>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.groups[group]" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    <div ng-if="modeldate==''"><span ng-message="required" class="change">Date is required</span> </div>
```

you can use the ng-if directive as above.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility for Angular:
I had to include an if - statement in the html part, I had to check if all variables of an URL that I produce are defined. I did it the following way and it seems to be a flexible approach. I hope it will be helpful for somebody.

The html part in the template:

```
    <div  *ngFor="let p of poemsInGrid; let i = index" >
        <a [routerLink]="produceFassungsLink(p[0],p[3])" routerLinkActive="active">
    </div>
```

And the typescript part:

```
  produceFassungsLink(titel: string, iri: string) {
      if(titel !== undefined && iri !== undefined) {
         return titel.split('/')[0] + '---' + iri.split('raeber/')[1];
      } else {
         return 'Linkinformation has not arrived yet';
      }
  }
```

Thanks and best regards,

Jan

Comment: Looks more like Angular than AngularJS.

Comment: @pzaenger, yes, but many answers for this question work for both, so I think some people, like myself, look at the answers anyway. Please let me know if you mind.

Comment: Well. At least you should mention this in your answer.

Comment: @pzaenger, thank you for this hint, I mentioned it now.

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are totally different. This belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

ng If else statement

```
ng-if="receiptData.cart == undefined ? close(): '' ;"
```