# How to conditionally display HTML in Angular partials

Tags: angularjs

How can I do this without the multiple `ng-if`s?

```
<h3 ng-if="data.link"><a href="{{data.link}}">{{data.name}}</a></h3>
<h3 ng-if="!data.link"><em>{{data.name}}</em></h3>
```

I've also considered `ng-switch`, but that requires an extra container element which I don't like.

Also tried tertiary expressions (e.g. `{{data.link?'option 1':'option 2'}}`) but that looks messy and it doesn't do well with HTML. `ng-bind-template` escapes HTML chars and also looks messy.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: i think there is no way. take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-in-angularjs-template

Comment: Thanks, ariel. You're probably right and there's no better way to mimic if-else.

Comment: if you are looking for a reusable element that can do this for multiple elements, you could always use a directive that encapsulates the logic