# AngularJS and HTML Table

Tags: json, angularjs

I have json that looks like this :

```
    [
        {
            "date": "25/06/2015",
            "details": [
                {
                    "p": "AM",
                    "b": "2500"
                },
                {
                    "p": "JL",
                    "b": "300"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "24/06/2015",
            "details": [
                {
                    "p": "AM",
                    "b": "2300"
                },
                {
                    "p": "JL",
                    "b": "1300"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to write the data to an html table using angularjs, but I want the value of `date.details.p` to determine which column the value of `date.details.b` should go in. So, for example the value `date.details.b` will always go in column 2 if `date.details.p` = 'AM'.

The JSON data will not always contain data that would relate to each column, nor can the order of the details array be guaranteed.

Any ideas gratefully received.

EDIT
The expected output would be

```
Date          AM      JL
25/06/2015    2500     300
24/06/2015    2300    1300
```

Comment: you have an error in your json code - you should remove the first `{` and last `}`

Comment: oops - edited to remove the offending braces

Comment: Could you maybe write the html that you'd expect from this input? I'm not sure how exactly is this table suppose to look ;)

Comment: @TomekSułkowski - edit again with expected output. Thanks for looking

Comment: hope this helps http://plnkr.co/edit/Di4OccGD2tvowvhLxyuf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info I can suggest you can use ngShow.

```
<tr>
    <td class="ColumnTwo">
        <span data-ng-show="checkAM(date)">{{date.details.p}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the function checkAM you can check if `date.details.p == "AM"`

Based on the situation you can use

ngSwitch
ngIf

Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810462/2489860

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>JL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="detail in item.details">
        <span ng-show="detail.p=='AM' && $index == 0">{{ detail.b }}</span>
        <span ng-show="detail.p=='JL' && $index == 1">{{ detail.b }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**You can see and run the complete code below:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.data = [
        {
            "date": "25/06/2015",
            "details": [
                {
                    "p": "AM",
                    "b": "2500"
                },
                {
                    "p": "JL",
                    "b": "300"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "24/06/2015",
            "details": [
                {
                    "p": "AM",
                    "b": "2300"
                },
                {
                    "p": "JL",
                    "b": "1300"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
   
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>JL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="detail in item.details">
        <span ng-show="detail.p=='AM' && $index == 0">{{ detail.b }}</span>
        <span ng-show="detail.p=='JL' && $index == 1">{{ detail.b }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```