# How to make use of ng-if , ng-else in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to compare id.here if id equals 5 do this, else do that.
How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="case" data-ng-if="data.id === '5' ">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" value="{{data.displayName}}"
            data-ng-model="customizationCntrl.check[data.id1]"
            data-ng-checked="{{data.status}}=='1'" onclick="return false;">{{data.displayName}}
        <br>
</div>
<div class="case" data-ng-else>
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" value="{{data.displayName}}"
            data-ng-model="customizationCntrl.check[data.id]"
            data-ng-checked="{{data.status}}=='1'">{{data.displayName}}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `ng-else` directive is it a core directive in angularjs?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates

Comment: Angular 4 now has it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) with expression and `ng-switch-when` for matching expression value:

```
<div ng-switch="data.id">
  <div ng-switch-when="5">...</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>...</div>
</div>
```

[Example is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2R3wYm6FpK7bGiRlyRm1?p=preview)

[Angular2 example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tNEjJ6fRfccwr39rLNvH?p=preview)

Comment: for Angular2 same answer, different syntax - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

Comment: you can also put `(data.id == 5)` for the switch statement expression and then `true` for the `when` expression if you find that clearer (and obviously only for an either/or value)

Comment: I don't think that will work @Simon_Weaver, as according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch), you can't use an expression for the `when`, so `true` will evaluate to the string `"true"`.

Answer (score 28):

There is no directive for **ng-else**

You can use **ng-if** to achieve **if(){..} else{..}** in angularJs.

For your current situation,

```
<div ng-if="data.id == 5">
<!-- If block -->
</div>
<div ng-if="data.id != 5">
<!-- Your Else Block -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I use. You can negate your `if` statement to achieve an `else`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try ternary operator.
Something like this

```
{{data.id === 5 ? "it's true" : "it's false"}}
```

Change your html code little bit and try this hope so it will be work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding some of the important concern about **ng directives**:-

1. Directives will respond the same place where it's execute.
2. **ng-else** concept is not there, you can with only **if**, or other flavor like **switch** statement.

Check out the below example:-

> <div ng-if="data.type == 'FirstValue' ">
>
> ```
> //different template with hoot data
> ```
>
> </div>
>
> <div ng-if="data.type == 'SecondValue' ">
>
> ```
>   //different template with story data
> ```
>
> </div>
>
> <div ng-if="data.type == 'ThirdValue' ">
>
> ```
>  //different template with article data
> ```
>
> </div>

As per datatype it is going to render any one of the div.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for ng if else in angular is :

```
<div class="case" *ngIf="data.id === '5'; else elsepart; ">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" value="{{data.displayName}}" 
    data-ng-model="customizationCntrl.check[data.id1]" data-ng-checked="
    {{data.status}}=='1'" onclick="return false;">{{data.displayName}}<br>
</div>
<ng-template #elsepart>
    <div class="case">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" value={{data.displayName}}"  
        data-ng-model="customizationCntrl.check[data.id]" data-ng-checked="
        {{data.status}}=='1'">{{data.displayName}}<br>
    </div> 
</ng-template>
```

Comment: ngif and else in used in higher version of angularjs like angular 2 and higher not in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-if="verifyName.indicator == 1"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
<span ng-if="verifyName.indicator == 0"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
```

try this code.
here verifyName.indicator value is coming from controller.
this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can write as:

```
<div class="case" ng-if="mydata.id === '5' ">
    <p> this will execute </p>
</div>
<div class="case" ng-if="mydata.id !== '5' ">
    <p> this will execute </p>
</div>
```

Comment: use this statement for if else condition in angularjs