# How can I use "*ngIf else"?

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular-template

I'm using Angular and I want to use `*ngIf else` (available since version 4) in this example:

```
<div *ngIf="isValid">
  content here ...
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isValid">
 other content here...
</div>
```

How can I achieve the same behavior with `ngIf else`?

Answer (score 1476, accepted):

**Angular 4 and 5**:

Using `else`:

```ts
<div *ngIf="isValid;else other_content">
    content here ...
</div>

<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

You can also use `then else`:

```ts
<div *ngIf="isValid;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>
<ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

Or `then` alone:

```ts
<div *ngIf="isValid;then content"></div>
<ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
```

**Demo:**

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XD5vLvmwTApcaHJ66Is1)

**Details:**

`<ng-template>`: is Angular’s own implementation of the `<template>` tag which is [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template):

> The HTML `<template>` element is a mechanism for holding client-side
> content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may
> subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

Comment: I hoped there was a way just to use <ng-template> without another tag like div, but oddly it is not... I know the <div> gets removed as you use it, but it's kinda weird as implementation I think.

Comment: @andreas You can use `<ng-container>` for the if-clause

Comment: Note: you can use `ng-container` for the container containing *ngIf, but not for the template

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I figured it out the hard way. But why? why didn't they allow `*ngIf ` to work on `ng-template`?

Comment: <div *ngIf="isValid;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div> it is not ignored. it is place fot injecting ng-template

Comment: Just to add a little info, assigning the template value(#templateValue) directly to component tag and using it with else syntax doesn't work. You should embed the component tag inside of `<ng-template>` and assign the template value to `ng-template` like, `<ng template #templateValue><your-component-tag></your-component-tag></ng-template>`

Comment: Hi @Bougarfaoui El houcine , Can I use <div #other_content>other content here...</div>  instead <ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>  ?

Means Can I use div rather than template ?

Comment: I've found that you can create if-then-elseif-elseif-elseif using ng-containers and ng-templates.

`<ng-container *ngIf="condition1; else ifelse1"></ng-container>

<ng-template #ifelse1><ng-contaier *ngIf="condition2; else ifelse2"></ng-container></ng-template>

<ng-template #ifelse2><ng-contaier *ngIf="condition2; else ifelse3"></ng-container></ng-template>
`

It's super verbose though, and the need for #ids for each ifelse feels clunky, for something that other web frameworks can accomplish with a single tag/operation.

Comment: Agree with @Josia, it's clunky. If would have been more natural to have an *ngElse much like the *ngSwitchDefault implementation. Because of that, we find it bad practice to use angular's "ngIf..else" construct due to its inconsistency, non intuitiveness and its template variable pollution. It's just weird. You are better off negating the *ngIf for your else blocks, it's more readable most of the time.

Comment: Having started out on Angular 1 and then left for React, now I am back on a project using Angular 5... is this real life? This construct is legitimately bad.

Comment: This also works in ionic 4 with angular 7. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Within a 'then' or 'else' statement we're specifying the id of the ng-template tag to use.  Isn't that basically a goto-statement?!

Comment: Is there a way to bind ngTemplateOutletContext when doing it this way?

Answer (score 267):

**In Angular 4.x.x**

You can use [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) in four ways to achieve a simple *if*-*else* procedure:

1. Just use **If**

   ```
   <div *ngIf="isValid">
       If isValid is true
   </div>
   ```
2. Using **If with Else** (please notice to **templateName**)

   ```
   <div *ngIf="isValid; else templateName">
       If isValid is true
   </div>

   <ng-template #templateName>
       If isValid is false
   </ng-template>
   ```
3. Using **If with Then** (please notice to **templateName**)

   ```
   <div *ngIf="isValid; then templateName">
       Here is never showing
   </div>

   <ng-template #templateName>
       If isValid is true
   </ng-template>
   ```
4. Using **If with Then and Else**

   ```
   <div *ngIf="isValid; then thenTemplateName else elseTemplateName">
       Here is never showing
   </div>

   <ng-template #thenTemplateName>
       If isValid is true
   </ng-template>

   <ng-template #elseTemplateName>
       If isValid is false
   </ng-template>
   ```

> Tip: **ngIf** evaluates the **expression** and then renders the **then** or **else**
> template in its place when the expression is truthy or falsy respectively.
>
> Typically the:
>
> - **then** template is the inline template of **ngIf** unless bound to a different value.
> - **else** template is blank unless it is bound.

Comment: It seems like the compiler does not accept `...; else ...`. Probably the `;` should be removed.

Comment: in angular-6, I tested with **`...; else ...`** and it worked

Comment: is there a way to do if-elseif-else?

Comment: What is the advantage of 4 over 2? Basically both of them has the same result with the difference that in the case of 4 we have an extra `<div>`  without any content.

Answer (score 58):

For **[Angular 9/8](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ngif-ngif-else-and-ngif-else-then-tutorial/)**

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-2-ngif-ngif-else-and-ngif-else-then-tutorial-with-example/)** **with Examples**

```
    export class AppComponent {
      isDone = true;
    }
```

**1) *ngIf**

```
    <div *ngIf="isDone">
      It's Done!
    </div>

    <!-- Negation operator-->
    <div *ngIf="!isDone">
      It's Not Done!
    </div>
```

**2) *ngIf and Else**

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="isDone; else elseNotDone">
      It's Done!
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #elseNotDone>
      It's Not Done!
    </ng-template>
```

**3) *ngIf, Then and Else**

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="isDone;  then iAmDone; else iAmNotDone">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #iAmDone>
      It's Done!
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #iAmNotDone>
      It's Not Done!
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: The question is, which one is better? From a performance point of view, I suspect that the 1st one has 2 directives which need to be evaluated independently, while the other 2 have only one. If you had this in a list/table of thousands of elements, would it not be slower?

Comment: Solution 1 is bad if default value is not truthy

Answer (score 49):

Just add new updates from Angular 8.

1. For case if with else, we can use **ngIf** and **ngIfElse**.

   ```html
   <ng-template [ngIf]="condition" [ngIfElse]="elseBlock">
     Content to render when condition is true.
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #elseBlock>
     Content to render when condition is false.
   </ng-template>
   ```
2. For case if with then, we can use **ngIf** and **ngIfThen**.

   ```html
   <ng-template [ngIf]="condition" [ngIfThen]="thenBlock">
     This content is never showing
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #thenBlock>
     Content to render when condition is true.
   </ng-template>
   ```
3. For case if with then and else, we can use **ngIf**, **ngIfThen**, and **ngIfElse**.

   ```html
   <ng-template [ngIf]="condition" [ngIfThen]="thenBlock" [ngIfElse]="elseBlock">
     This content is never showing
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #thenBlock>
     Content to render when condition is true.
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #elseBlock>
     Content to render when condition is false.
   </ng-template>
   ```

Comment: Great! We have recently moved to angular 8

Comment: 1 is not working, i tried the condition to be false but it doesnt display the template elseBlock

Comment: @rosiejaneenomar I think something wrong with your code. If can, u can give me sample of your code.

Comment: @rosiejaneenomar please follow the guide from Angular document https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 41):

If isShow is true then the first line execute, otherwise secondline executes, because **elseBlockShow** is working as a reference variable.

```html
<div *ngIf="isShow; else elseBlockShow">
  Text to show for If
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlockShow>
  Text to show for else block
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 35):

To work with observable, this is what I usually do to display if the observable array consists of data.

```
<div *ngIf="(observable$ | async) as listOfObject else emptyList">
   <div >
        ....
    </div>
</div>
 <ng-template #emptyList>
   <div >
        ...
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 25):

Here's some nice and clean syntax on Angular's NgIf and using the `else` statement. In short, you will declare an [ElementRef](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/element-refs-in-angular-templates) on an element and then reference it in the `else` block:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn; else loggedOut">
   Welcome back, friend.
</div>

<ng-template #loggedOut>
  Please friend, login.
</ng-template>
```

I've taken this example from [NgIf, Else, Then](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then) which I found to be really well explained.

It also demonstrates using the `<ng-template>` syntax:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isLoggedIn" [ngIfElse]="loggedOut">
  <div>
    Welcome back, friend.
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loggedOut>
  <div>
    Please friend, login.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And also using `<ng-container>` if that's what you're after:

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="isLoggedIn; then loggedIn; else loggedOut">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loggedIn>
  <div>
    Welcome back, friend.
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loggedOut>
  <div>
    Please friend, login.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Source is taken from [here on Angular's NgIf and Else syntax](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then).

Comment: I don't find using template for just a single line nice and clean

Comment: @arunwithasmile same, it is just the example given for both syntaxes. *ngIf is the way to go unless needed.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `<ng-container>` and `<ng-template>` to achieve this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isValid; then template1 else template2"></ng-container>

<ng-template #template1>
     <div>Template 1 contains</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2>
     <div>Template 2 contains </div>
</ng-template>
```

You can find the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) Live demo below:

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions58514584?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 9):

"bindEmail" will check if email is available or not. If email does exist then Logout will show. Otherwise Login will show.

```
<li *ngIf="bindEmail;then logout else login"></li>
<ng-template #logout><li><a routerLink="/logout">Logout</a></li></ng-template>
<ng-template #login><li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li></ng-template>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If it were correct, then it still wouldn't add any value because the accepted answer shows already how to do it.

Answer (score 9):

```html
<div *ngIf="isValid; else templateName">
  If isValid is true
</div>

<ng-template #templateName>
  If isValid is false
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-can-i-use-ngif-else/46833339#46833339

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the JavaScript short ternary conditional operator `?` in Angular like this:

```
{{doThis() ? 'foo' : 'bar'}}
```

or

```
<div [ngClass]="doThis() ? 'foo' : 'bar'">
```

Answer (score 6):

An ngif expression resulting value won’t just be the Boolean true or false.

If the expression is just an object, it still evaluates it as truthiness.

If the object is undefined, or non-existent, then ngif will evaluate it as falseness.

Common use is if an object loaded, exist, and then display the content of this object, otherwise display "loading.......".

```
 <div *ngIf="!object">
     Still loading...........
 </div>

<div *ngIf="object">
     <!-- the content of this object -->

           object.info, object.id, object.name ... etc.
 </div>
```

Another example:

```
  things = {
 car: 'Honda',
 shoes: 'Nike',
 shirt: 'Tom Ford',
 watch: 'Timex'
 };

 <div *ngIf="things.car; else noCar">
  Nice car!
 </div>

<ng-template #noCar>
   Call a Uber.
</ng-template>

 <!-- Nice car ! -->
```

Another example:

```
<div *ngIf="things.car; let car">
   Nice {{ car }}!
 </div>
<!-- Nice Honda! -->
```

[ngif template](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/)

[ngif Angular 4](https://alligator.io/angular/ngif-new-features-angular4/)

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities to use an *if* condition on an HTML tag or templates:

1. *ngIf directive from CommonModule, on HTML tag;
2. if-else

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```js
**ngIf else**

<div *ngIf="isConditionTrue;else other_condition">
    your content here
</div>

<ng-template #other_condition>other content here...</ng-template>

**ngIf then else**

<div *ngIf="isConditionTrue;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>
<ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>


**ngIf then**

<div *ngIf="isConditionTrue;then content"></div>
<ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Angular 17, you can use [built-in control flow](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow), an alternative template syntax for conditionally showing, hiding or repeating elements. It allows you to do `if else` like the following:

```
@if (isValid) {
  content here ...
} @else {
  other content here...
}
```

With this syntax, it's not necessary to use `ng-template` for the `else` case.
Additionally, it allows `@else if`, which has not been possible before.

> As of Angular 17, control flow is in developer preview and may change before becoming stable.

Answer (score 5):

### Syntax for ngIf/Else

```
<div *ngIf=”condition; else elseBlock”>Truthy condition</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Falsy condition</ng-template>
```

[image]

### Using NgIf / Else/ Then explicit syntax

To add a *then* template, we just have to bind it to a template explicitly.

```
<div *ngIf=”condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock”> ... </div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>Then template</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Else template</ng-template>
```

[image]

### Observables with NgIf and Async Pipe

[For more details](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`ng-template`

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition1" [ngIfElse]="template2">
        ...
</ng-template>


<ng-template #template2> 
        ...
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 4.0 `if..else` syntax is quite similar to conditional operators in  Java.

In Java you use to `"condition?stmnt1:stmnt2"`.

In  Angular 4.0 you use `*ngIf="condition;then stmnt1 else stmnt2"`.

Comment: looks like Oracle case when expression.. :-)

Comment: You're referring to the [ternary operator which exists in most C-based languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) but this is closer to [Kotlin's if expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression).

Comment: condition?stmnt1:stmnt2, this doesn't work only in java. So it is not only java related

Answer (score 4):

```
<div *ngIf="show; else elseBlock">Text to show</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Alternate text while primary text is hidden</ng-template>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62749789/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

## In Angular 4, 5 and 6

We can simply create a *template reference variable* <sup>[2](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)</sup> and link that to the else condition inside an *ngIf directive

The possible *syntaxes* <sup>[1](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#syntax)</sup> are:

```
<!-- Only If condition -->
<div *ngIf="condition">...</div>
<!-- or -->
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition"><div>...</div></ng-template>


<!-- If and else conditions -->
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">...</div>
<!-- or -->
<ng-template #elseBlock>...</ng-template>

<!-- If-then-else -->
<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>...</ng-template>


<!-- If and else conditions (storing condition value locally) -->
<div *ngIf="condition as value; else elseBlock">{{value}}</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>...</ng-template>
```

**DEMO:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feumnt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

**Sources:**

1. *[NgIf - directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#syntax)*
2. *[Template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)*

Comment: Your answer states it's valid for Angular 4 through 6. It made sense 2018 when you wrote it but now, 4 years later, it suggests that it's **not** necessarily valid for the latest version. I just used it in Angular 13 and it works perfectly. You may want to consider updating the formulation to make your answer from great to even better.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div *ngIf="this.model.SerialNumber != '';then ConnectedContent else DisconnectedContent" class="data-font">    </div>

<ng-template #ConnectedContent class="data-font">Connected</ng-template>
<ng-template #DisconnectedContent class="data-font">Disconnected</ng-template>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49882364/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

So, this isn't actually using ng-if but many of the suggestions appear to deal with writing text in a conditional statement. I think this way is the best way to do that with least code or complication. You be the judge.

```
<div>{{variable == null ? 'Testing1' : 'Testing2'}}<div>
OR
<div>{{variable == null ? var1 : var2 }}<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The long waiting feature to support the if, else-if, else has been supported in Angular 17.

you can do it by following the below syntax:

```
`@if() {
   <div>Inside if condtion</div>
} @else if() {
   <div>Inside if else condtion</div>
} @else {
   <div>Inside else</div>
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about with is to have two flags in the component and two ngIfs for the corresponding two flags.

It was simple and worked well with material as ng-template and material were not working well together.

Comment: Can you [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52419833/edit) one or more code examples? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)