# How can I use if, else if in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

My question duplicat at [How to use *ngIf else in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular/43006589#43006589)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: use == (or better ===) instead of = for a comparison

Comment: What have you tried? Show your template code.

Comment: Sorry I meant *ngIf in HTML page for Angular2

Comment: <span translate *ngIf="menuItem.title != 'unapprove'; then menuItem.title == 'approve' ; else #anotherMenu">{{ menuItem.title }}</span> like this

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: That statement does not make much sense. What is the result of that `*ngIf`? Are you trying to show something? Ignoring syntax for a moment, what you have there is 2  equality checks with no output.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4/43006589#43006589

Comment: Thx you a lots.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Not a dupe if use multiple if's,

Comment: @Swoox It was initially very unclear what the question was about until he updated it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer tbh he didn't update it you just misread it

Comment: @Swoox that's not true. At first he had not even HTML in his question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ah yeah I see, sorry. But was before your answer :P

Comment: @swoop I didn't check properly after I came back from the search. Probably just too many open tabs ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait it's simpler then that. In template:

```
<div *ngIf = "name == 'a'">if a</div>
<div *ngIf = "name == 'b'">if b</div>
<div *ngIf = "name == 'c'">if c</div>
```

**edit**

If you want to make it dynamic do *ngFor let name of names and do ngIf on {{name}}

```
<div *ngFor="let name of names">
<p *ngIf = "name == {{name}}">Your if</p>
</div> //something like this.
```

Comment: so What about in case name == d?. I just need use if elseif and else by the way.

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: Gave an example

Comment: It close to my answer what I want but My question was not clearly. so sorry

Comment: @WanadjananKlinnooch No worries some creative mind will fix every problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(name == 'a'){
  console.log("1");
} else if(name == 'b') { 
  console.log("2");
} else {
  console.log("other");
}
```

inline:

```
*ngIf="name == 'a' ? test('1') : name == 'b' ? test('2) : test('other)"
```

test is a function that you have to create... or do something else..

Comment: Sorry I meant *ngIf for Angular2