# How to add component on button click in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I am a beginner in Angular and facing an issue in development.
In my application displaying data of customer in grid and on clicking row a div under this row will expand and customer related detailed data will be displayed in that div. I want to hit the database on click and then data will bind to the template and then that HTML will be injected under clicked row. I have no idea how to do this. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: make use of structural directives *ngIf or even parent child components , there are multiple ways to achieve it . its too broad a question to answer i feel

Comment: @RahulSingh : Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` directive, as the documentation states:

> Conditionally includes a template based on the value of an expression

`ngIf` evaluates the expression and then renders the then or else template in its place when expression is truthy or falsy respectively. Typically the:

- `then` template is the inline template of ngIf unless bound to a
  different value.
- `else` template is blank unless it is bound.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006589/5346095) for better understanding.