# *ngIf with multiple conditions not working

Tags: angular

I want to show the full table when the 'all' radio button is clicked. I want to show the row containing only 'male' when the male radio button is clicked. And I want to show the row containing only 'female' when the female radio button is clicked. All it shows is a blank page. My code is:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="r" [(ngModel)] = "chk1"> All
    <input type="radio" name="r" [(ngModel)] = "chk2"> male
    <input type="radio" name="r" [(ngModel)] = "chk3"> female
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf = "(chk1 || chk2">
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf = "chk1 || chk3">
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>female</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In the first *ngIf there is a syntax error, remove the '('

Comment: I imagine there are messages in the console; I'd recommend reading them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \*ngIf else in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you're supposed to use radio buttons. All inputs should be bound to the same variable, but have a different value:

```
  <form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="o" value="all" [(ngModel)]="option" /> All</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="o" value="male" [(ngModel)]="option" /> Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="o" value="female" [(ngModel)]="option" /> Female</label>
  </form>

  Chosen option: {{ option }}
```

This way, you can use

```
*ngIf="option === 'male' || option === 'all'"
```

or

```
*ngIf="option === 'female' || option === 'all'"
```

Note that doing it like this is pretty inefficient. You'd better create a filtered copy of the array every time the option changes, from your controller (thanks to `(ngModelChange)="createFilteredCopy()"`), and then iterate on the filtered copy, without using any ngIf.