# Using *ngIf along with angular4 custom pipes

Tags: angular

I am using a custom pipe that filter the array based upon the first alphabet in string of array (phone directory style). Whenever i change the alphabet parameter the pipe return the filtered array and i display it using *ngFor. If no match is found it return empty array and my diplay are is blank.

I want that if pipe return empty array my display area should show a div 'No record found'. How can I do that.

```
<div *ngIf="currentList.length > 0; else nodata" id="outerContainer">
    <div id="listContainer">
        <div class="listItem" *ngFor="let list of currentList | listFilter : listfilterChar" (click)="openContactList()">
            <div class="listInfo">
              <h3>
                {{list.Name}}
              </h3>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div id="alphabetContainer">
      <p *ngFor="let letter of alphabetArray">
        <span class="alphabetContainer" (click)='setListFiltercharacter($event)'>{{letter}}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the above code on clicking **span.alphabetContainer**, the variable **listfilterChar** is updated with alphabet and **pipe** filter the array. But if no contact found with matching initial alphabet display area remain blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \*ngIf else in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular)

Comment: But I think using another div with negated value is much more readable than this ngIf-else.

Comment: hey, where is your else nodata div? in that div you should mention your error. it will execute as if array is not empty or greater than zero it will show {{list.Name}} else nodata div.

Comment: I think the pipe is not directly manipulating currentList array. It returns a new array so currentList.length == 0, not working

Comment: Not related but filter/sort pipes are not encouraged in Angular2+

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this out

```
<div class="listItem" *ngFor="let list of currentList | listFilter : listfilterChar" (click)="openContactList()">
    <div class="listInfo">
        <h3>
            {{list.Name}}
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(currentList | listFilter : listfilterChar).length === 0">
    "No record found"
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

Following this [article](https://netbasal.com/using-pipe-results-in-angular-templates-430683fa2213), a better approach will be to do this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf=”(currentList | listFilter : listfilterChar) as result”>

  <div *ngFor=”let item of result”>
    {{item}}
  </div>

  <b *ngIf="!result.length">No record found</b>

</ng-container>
```