# Ionic 3 Angular NgIf

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an error when I create my ngIf in the img tag here is my code:

```
<img name="{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="jaquette" [src]="jaquette" *ngIf="results.poster_path as 'null' || ''; then jaquette == noJaquette else jaquette == themoviedbServicesProvider?.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path" />
```

Do you have an idea of the problem ?
Thank you

---

Thank you for answering, ok I put you a little more code. For information, if I remove the NgIf everything works correctly.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-sm>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let results of themoviedbServicesProvider?.searchMovie?.results; let i = index" (click)="choiceGetMovie(results.id, language)">
          <img name="{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="jaquette" [src]="jaquette" *ngIf="results.poster_path as 'null' || ''; then jaquette == noJaquette else jaquette == themoviedbServicesProvider?.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path" />
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
              {{ results.title }}
            </ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

[image: error]

Comment: there are many possible errors. please provide some more code or at least the required part.

Comment: The expression ngIf is not corrrect. Move it to a method wich returns true or false. Then in ngif is for template names which you don't seem to have anyway

Comment: removing **|| ''** I have no more mistakes which gives ->  
`<img name="{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="jaquette" [src]="jaquette" *ngIf="results.poster_path as null; then jaquette == noJaquette else jaquette == themoviedbServicesProvider?.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path" />` however, I do not understand your last sentence **Vega**

Comment: I meant that 'then' in *ngIf is not used in the same way as in typescript/js. See : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#using-non-inlined-then-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting "-1" stupidly, I found the solution. Thanks anyway to the people who answered. Here's how I solved my problem.

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-sm>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let results of themoviedbServicesProvider?.searchMovie?.results; let i = index" (click)="choiceGetMovie(results.id, language)">
          <ng-container *ngIf="themoviedbServicesProvider.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path === 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300null'; then noJaquette else realJaquette"></ng-container>
            <ng-template #realJaquette><img name="{{i}}" [src]="themoviedbServicesProvider.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path" /></ng-template>
            <ng-template #noJaquette><img name="{{i}}" src="../../assets/imgs/no-image.PNG" /></ng-template>
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
              {{ results.title }}
            </ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have made an edit to question instead of answering it. 
Ok `jaquette` is your image src address. I think you are

`*ngIf="results.poster_path as 'null' || ''; then jaquette == noJaquette else jaquette == themoviedbServicesProvider?.baseUrlConfig + results.poster_path"`

trying to change `jaquette` based on if-then-else.

Now that's not how [*ngIf then else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular) work. `then` and `else` are for template reference.

Define two functions in component class.

```
 showImage(results) { return true }//or false based on results
  getJaqutte(results) {
     return results+'your logic'; 
  }
```

then use like

```
  <img name="{{i}}" [src]= "getJaqutte(results)" *ngIf="showImage(results)" />
```

Comment: unfortunately I can not do it because "results.poster_path" can only be read in the html part of the asyncrone. If no, I would have done it. in ionic the router module does not work.