# How to fix the following ngIf directive in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am very new at angular and I tried to learn angular 5 from basic. I just tried the ngIf directive and I found that if part has not got any problem but when I use else part as in the following code the error saying  is not a known element. I think there is something wrong in the else part. Help me.

now I edited the quote and it still sends the same error. Is there something I'm missing. I'm very new to angular.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      template: `
        <h2 *ngIf = "isVisible; else elseBlock" >
            This is visible
        </h2>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <h2>
              This is not visible.
          </h2>
        </ng-template>
      ` ,
      styles: []
    })

    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
      public name = "Dipesh";
      public isVisible = true;
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \*ngIf else in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular) - you need to put the `else` part inside the quotes.

Comment: not working though

Comment: it look correct for angular5 , are u sure you not using newest angular6?

Comment: I was just going through tutorials on angular 5 and I stuck in this thing.

Comment: If the answer helped you solve the problem, do not forget to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*ngIf = "isVisible"; else elseBlock
```

should be

```
*ngIf = "isVisible; else elseBlock"
```

You had the closing `"` in the wrong place ending the `*ngIf` prematurely.

Comment: @DipeshPaudel - it does work. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqjfm7). Your only problem was the one I corrected above in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is missing quote

```
 @Component({

  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h2 *ngIf="isVisible; else elseBlock">
            This is visible
        </h2>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <h2>
              This is not visible.
          </h2>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  isVisible:boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    this.isVisible=true;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example from angular.io docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-else',
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
    show = {{show}}
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="show; else elseBlock">Text to show</div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>Alternate text while primary text is hidden</ng-template>
`
})
class NgIfElse {
  show: boolean = true;
}
```

Like @Joe Clay said, you have to putting your else inside the quotes.