# Angular 5 *ngIf else rendering div despite nocontent

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using

**Angular 5.2**

**Firestore**

Using `*ngIf isContent else noContent`, I am trying to render an Observable only if it's populated with data. The logic isn't hitting the else statement. It's rendering `isContent` even when there's no data. I have poured through these [similar stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular) and it looks like my syntax is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="months2025 | async as months; else nocontent">

  #### RENDERING REGARDLESS OF MONTHS2025 ####
  <div class="column">
    <h1>2025</h1> #### <-- THIS SHOWS UP ####
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let month of months">
        <a href={{month.url}}> {{ month.fileName }} </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</ng-container>

#### NOT RENDERING WHEN NOCONTENT ####
<ng-template #nocontent>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the `component.ts`

```
export class MinutesComponent {
  monthsArray2025: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  months2025: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.monthsArray2025 = afs.collection<any>('minutes', ref => ref.where('year', '==', 2025);
    this.months2025 = this.monthsArray2025.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16173) about this topic. For now, the simplest workaround I found is a pair of *ngIf containers.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="months2025 | async as months">
  <ng-container *ngIf="months.length > 0; else nocontent">
    <div class="column">
      <li *ngFor="let month of months">
        <a href={{month.url}}> {{ month.fileName }} </a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #nocontent>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are getting an empty array from your observable i.e. `[]` which is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

You need to check for length as well.

<s>`<ng-container *ngIf="(months2025  | async) as months && months.length>0; else nocontent">`</s>

As I mentioned in my comment there is an open issue to allow a construct where such a check is possible in [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16173).

One workaround is to use a map to force undefined/null when you have empty array.

```
 this.months2025 = this.monthsArray2025.valueChanges().pipe(map(mnths=>mnths && mnths.length>0?mnths:undefined));
```

Another is to use two different `*ngIf` as mentioned by @John [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51033889/4826457)

Comment: That hits the else statement effectively, but does not display when I populate months2025 with data, e.g. when length > 0 is true.

Comment: Sorry was checking length of observable instead of array. Try the update

Comment: Hmm. This `*ngIf="months2025 | async as months && months.length>0; ..."` and this *ngIf="(months2025 | async as months && months.length>0); ..."` and this *ngIf="(months2025 | async as months) && months.length>0; ..."` and this *ngIf="((months2025 | async as months) && months.length>0); ..."` all lead to template parse errors in the console: `Unexpected token &&`

Comment: If this changed one doesn't work , I will try and post later... I am outside.