# Add an if else clause within *ngFor in Angular / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a project in Angular 7 with Typescript an am trying to optimise the following (simplified) code snippet:

```
<div *ngIf="!showAll">

  <div *ngFor="let filter of filters | slice:0:5;">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="filter.selected">{{ filter.value }}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="showAll">

  <div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="filter.selected">{{ filter.value }}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>

</div>
```

If the boolean `showAll` is true, I want to show all values of my `filters` array, if it isn't I want to slice this array to only get the first 5 entries. Is this possible in one line of code?

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ngIf with multiple conditions to achieve that.

```
  <div *ngFor="let filter of filters ; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox *ngIf="showAll || i < 5" [checked]="filter.selected">{{ filter.value }}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <div *ngFor="let filter of showAll ? filters : (filters | slice:0:5) ">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="filter.selected">{{ filter.value }}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```