# How would you get a value from the variable using a template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this is some basic stuff for a lot of you but I'm trying to figure it out.

I saw this other post on doing ngif else conditionals with templates: [How to use *ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else).

```
<div *ngIf="isValid;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>
  <ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
  <ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

So, how do you get the template to know to translate the condition to its value.

**e.g. someObj.someProperty**
If it exists then display it else display a text message.

```
<div *ngIf="someObj.someProperty;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>
  <ng-template #content>someObj.someProperty</ng-template>
  <ng-template #other_content>not specified</ng-template>
```

FYI: I'm using https://stackblitz.com/

Why would I use that and not my desktop one may ask.

Easy my machine is locked down and I'm trying to get admin rights so I can install software on it. Try learning something with notepad and no way to run the code.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `someObj.someProperty` in double curly brackets? Like this: `{{ someObj.someProperty }}`?

Comment: Yes I have. Also I'm using https://stackblitz.com/ , perhaps its an issue using a web page to do this?

Comment: wrote a stackblitz for you. enjoy. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frs4pz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Can't tell. You haven't shared the URL to the StackBlitz you're working with.

Comment: Sorry been on the help desk line for past 20 minuets trying to get someone to let me have some softare on this box. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5yush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I wouldn't use `*ngIf`.

Consider:

```html
<div> {{ someObj?.someProperty || 'other content to render' }}</div>
```

If `someObj?.someProperty` evaluates to a truthy (a non empty string), that will get rendered, otherwise the string `'other content to render'` will be rendered.