# Semicolon in *ngIf directive with else block - Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

Recently I used a `*ngIf` directive **with an else block** in Angular and was wondering why in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) the examples use a semicolon (`<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>`) as this seems to work without the semicolon as well.

Does this have any side effects not to use the semicolon? Or is this just a more cleaner way to code?

Comment: It is for a else block. You can then write `<ng-template #elseBlock></ng-template>` that will be used in case `condition` fails. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43006550/6513921

Comment: I know that it is used for an else block. but I want to know why it is needed since it seems to work without the semicolon as well. maybe I wrote my question a bit too vague. I will edit my question.

Comment: Please note that [one of the examples](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#shorthand-syntax) in the documentation doesn't have the semicolon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Forethought**

On retrospect, this is a very interesting question. The actual question is `<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">` works as expected. But also does `<div *ngIf="condition else elseBlock">`, so what gives? What actually is the need for the semi-colon?

**Explanation**

It turns out the Angular [microsyntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) specification that defines how `*ngIf` is expanded to `[ngIf]` is quite flexible and difficult to grasp initially. The official Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) doesn't go in-depth. A good explanation could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mhevery/d3530294cff2e4a1b3fe15ff75d08855) and [here](https://unicorn-utterances.com/posts/angular-templates-start-to-source/#microsyntax-rules). Gist of the explanation is that the microsyntax definition is of the form

> `*:prefix="( :let | :expression ) (';' | ',')? ( :let | :as | :keyExp )*"`
>
> - `:prefix`: HTML attribute key.
> - `:key`: HTML attribute key.
> - `:local`: local variable name used in the template.
> - `:export`: value exported by the directive under a given name.
> - `:experession`: standard angular expression
> - `:keyExp = :key ":"? :expression ("as" :local)? ";"?`
> - `:let = "let" :local "=" :export ";"?`
> - `:as = :export "as" :local ";"?`

It appears the semi-colon is optional. Additionally in our case, the `else` block is a key expression and it could be seen that the colon is optional which we aren't using at the moment. So theoretically we could also use `<div *ngIf="condition else: elseBlock">`. As such, the `ngFor` can also be used without any semi-colon. So the following block will also work

```html
<div *ngFor="let n of arr let i=index let f=first let l=last">
  {{ n }}
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcxffu)

Answer (score -1):

The semicolon is only required if you are using the "else" block.
So,
`<div *ngIf="condition">`  (without the semicolon) is the canonical form when not using an 'else', but `<div *ngIf="condition;">` (with the semicolon) is also valid,
and `<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">` is the required form when using 'else'.

There are also couple of other interesting syntax options that I wasn't aware of until I looked carefully at the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is the required form when using 'else'"? Because it still works without the semicolon.

Comment: wasn't aware that it worked without the semicolon, thanks.