# ngIf - working with server side condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a condition that I am unable to determine if "not":

```
*ngIf="searchResults['@odata.count'] !== null && searchResults['@odata.count'] >= 0"
```

Note, this does not work:

```
*ngIf="searchResults['@odata.count'] == null && searchResults['@odata.count']< 0"
```

that I want to write an ngIf "not". Similar to:

```
*ngIf="!(searchResults['@odata.count'] !== null && searchResults['@odata.count'] >= 0)"
```

Is there a way to do this solely working with the condition given?

Comment: You mean without doing the `!()` part?  Also, a small note that this isn't server side logic.  Angular runs in the client's browser.

Comment: !() does not work. yes, without that.

Comment: The inverse of `A !== B && C >= D` is `A === B || C < D`

Comment: I would think that is the answer also but it does not work.

Comment: What is the value and type of the value of `searchResults['@odata.count']` in the case that you are seeing it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you could use:

1. use `*ngIf *condition*; else tempalteRef` [How to use *ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else;)
2. separate logic in getter(or method):
   in .ts file

```
get showSearch() {
  return searchResults['@odata.count'] !== null && searchResults['@odata.count'] >= 0;
}
```

in template use `*ngIf=showSearch` and `*ngIf=!showSearch`

Comment: also, if searchResults['@odata.count'] == null, how it could be less than zero together with null ? searchResults['@odata.count']< 0