# Angular - show error message on submit when form is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

I have this form where an error message shows under every field if I leave it empty or invalid.

```
<form #projectForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

     <div class="form-group col-md-6" [class.has-error]="codeControl.invalid && codeControl.touched">
        <label  class="control-label">code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="projet.code" id="code" name="code" #codeControl="ngModel">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="codeControl.invalid && codeControl.touched">code is required </span>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group col-md-6" [class.has-error]="libelleControl.invalid && libelleControl.touched">
        <label class="control-label">libelle</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="projet.libelle" id="libelle" name="libelle" #libelleControl="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="libelleControl.invalid && libelleControl.touched"> libelle is required </span>
      </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >submit </button>

    
  </form>
```

But when it comes to the submit button , I don't want the submit button to be disabled until the form is valid, instead I want the submit button border to become red and a red error message shows under the submit button when clicked and the form is invalid. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
on your component

```
success: any;

constructor () 
{
this.success = true;
}

onSubmit(){

if(this.yourform.invalid){
    this.success= false; 
    return;
}
```

}

on your html

```
 <div *ngIf="success;then content else other_content"></div>    
  <ng-template #content>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >submit </button>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #other_content>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="border: 2px solid red">submit 
  </button>
   <!-- your error message goes here -->
 </ng-template>
```

i copied the *ngIf here at [How to use *ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with simple getter to manage state of the 'submit btn'

```
get isFormValid():boolean {
  this.ngForm && this.ngForm.valid;
}
```

then

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [class.cssClassToManageBtnState]="isFormValid" >submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to override the default behaviour of submit button. So, remove the button type as submit and add click event to it

```
  <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary" >submit </button>
```

Remove the submit event in form tag

```
<form #projectForm="ngForm">
```

Add the conditional class to the button

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="projectForm.valid ? '' : 'invalid-form-btn'" >submit </button>
<span *ngIf="!projectForm.valid">The form is not valid </span>

.invalid-form-btn {
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
```