# *ngIf to toggle parent div without affecting the child

Tags: angular-ng-if

Not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to do an *ngIf for ONLY the targeted element, without affecting anything inside?

For example, in the code below:

```
<div *ngIf="condition" class="outerDiv">
   <div class="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

if this condition is false, I would like it to still have:

```
<div class="innerDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible because HTML is structured like tree. If you delete higher branch, child branches are deleted as well.

I would suggest having wrappers for children and use `ngIf else` like answered over here: [How to use *ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else)

#### EDIT:

Apparently, you can *hide* the parent using `visiblity: hidden` and set `visibility: visible` on the child. I'd recommend using `ngClass` and set classes based on conditions.