# Another condition in *ngif

Tags: angular, typescript

it is possible to make another condition in ***ngIf**. I try add condition like this in *ngIf `commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id)?item.quantity - commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0:item.quantity; else notFound` but i got error this error message `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:Parser Error: Missing expected`.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of commonService.indexList$.getValue(); let i = index" class="Box">
 <span *ngIf="commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id)?item.quantity - commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0:item.quantity; else notFound"> 

</span>
<ng-template #notFound>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: isnt that simple OR with ELSE?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else) something, that could help?

Comment: I need to add another condition like this`commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id)?` in `*ngIf` to check id

Comment: I dont see it, just evaluate to false - `else` will kick in

Comment: If I just use this code `item.quantity - commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0` wihtout add this `commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id)?` all list will change

Comment: In an *ngIf directive you can put only an expression that can be true or false.
I don't know if your item.quantity is boolean, if not it won't work.

However, 
`*ngIf="commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id) ? (item.quantity - commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0) : item.quantity; else notFound"`

Comment: @AntonioEsposito `item.quantity` is not boolean. it is number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do something like that, *ngIf accepts logical operators only Or you can use function and it's result should be true or false only!

If you have a complex condition you can define a function in your component.ts and use it in *ngIf

for example:

```
check(item){
   if (this.commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id)){
      if(item.quantity - this.commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0)
         return true;
      else 
         return false;
   }
   else
      return false;
 }
```

and in your template

```
<span *ngIf="check(item)"> 

</span>
```

Comment: I got error `item.id`. it come from `*ngFor="let item of commonService.indexList$.getValue(); let i = index"`

Comment: I wrote the code as example, you need to edit the function to pass item, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Luay, NOP, *ngIf can be use with number, string or object not only with booleans, e.g. is variable1=0, variable2=4,variable3="something", variable4=null, variable5='', variable6={}, *ngIf="variable1", *ngIf="variable4" and *ngIf="variable5" is false, *ngIf="variable3", *ngIf="variable3 and *ngIf="variable6" is true

Comment: Yes that true, you can pass what you mentioned but all of them one way or another expression returns true or false (object defined or not / empty or equal to zero), and I think (based on the question) he is beginner so mentioning all that cases doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes true.., I'm new in programming..Thank you so much all for your answer and comment

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer above is correct, it is worth to mention that nothing's wrong with containing your logic in *ngIf - you just need to keep the spaces to avoid parse errors

```
<span *ngIf="commonService.indexKey$.getValue().includes(item.id) ? item.quantity - commonService.liststock$.getValue() > 0 : item.quantity; else notFound">
```