# How to make ngIf condition for user login - app-container router-outlet

Tags: authentication, angular-ng-if, router-outlet, angular12

I am repeatedly running in an issue which I believe has everything to do with my ngIf conditions in my app.component.html. Here is my code:

```
<!-- nav -->
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="user">
     <div class="sidebar" >
        <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
    </div> 
     <div class="main-panel">
        <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>
        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 



<!-- main app container -->
<div class="app-container" [ngClass]="{ 'bg-light': user }" *ngIf="!user">
    <alert></alert>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

There are two ngIf conditions here.

If I have only the first one then when I log out I cannot redirect to my login screen. What happens is the Navbar and sidebar disappear but the page itself remains although the URL says it's at login. The router-outlet doesn't go away.

If I have only the second one then my sidebar links don't work and the router-outlet is basically blank.

If I have both conditions then once logged in and using the sidebar, the URL changes but the page doesn't load.

If I have neither condition then Navbar and sidebar appear on login screen when they ought not.

Help!

I'm not very proficient in Angular just yet so I was hoping for some direction here.

My latest thought is to have an `*ngIf user; else` something. I'm not sure. How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! This question is exactly what I was thinking but couldn't get it to work but now it works!!

[How to use *ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else)

This is the solution:

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="user; else loggedOut">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>
        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<ng-template #loggedOut>
    <div class="app-container" [ngClass]="{ 'bg-light': user }">
        <alert></alert>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Whoop whoop!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use guards.

You can then redirect the users to the log in page or to the authenticated page depending if the user exists (is authenticated) or not.