# How to express Angular condition more succinctly

Tags: angular

How can I write the following more succinctly?

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr *ngFor='let entry of m_myArray; let i = index'>
            <td *ngIf="i == m_myArray.length - 1"><a href=”” (click)="$event.preventDefault();OnShowRecentRecord()">{{getDateFormat(entry.date)}}</a></td>
            <td *ngIf="i != m_myArray.length - 1"{{getDateFormat(entry.date)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If `i == m_myArray.length - 1` I want the table entry to be a link, otherwise just text. I have used a test on `i` against `m_myArray.length` twice and feel like I should be able to use `ngElse` (or similar) to avoid that.

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf? You _can_ use if and else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \*ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the angular world, when you are using `ngFor` directive, you have access to many variables. The ones that you are looking for is:

- `last` which is true for the last element (exactly) for your case

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr *ngFor='let entry of m_myArray; let i = index; let isLast = last'>
            <td *ngIf="isLast"><a href=”” (click)="$event.preventDefault();OnShowRecentRecord()">{{getDateFormat(entry.date)}}</a></td>
            <td *ngIf="!isLast">{{getDateFormat(entry.date)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c4keyk?file=src/app/app.component.html) code sample

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let entry of m_myArray; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="i == m_myArray.length - 1; else notLastIndex">
        <td><a href="””">link</a></td>
      </div>

      <ng-template #notLastIndex>
        <td>{{ entry }}</td>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```