# How to use ngif condition in angular

Tags: html, angular

Approve and Publish


 Important! You're about to approve

dustry Formile Deliverable

Content to render when condition is true. -->

div class="form-group"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use "\*ngIf else"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-can-i-use-ngif-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use simply `if` condition

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
   Condition content
</div>
```

if you use `if` with `else` condition

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else secondCondition">
   Condition content
</div>

<ng-template #secondCondition>
  secondCondition content
</ng-template>
```

Comment: How to add condition yes and no in that code

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="your condition"></div>
```