# Based on if else conditon show the sidebars in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am beginner in angular. I am working on project  like want to give if else condition in root and if means shows one sidebar1 and else means sidebar2.i do not know am doing correct or not

```
In app.component.html
<div *ngIf ="show; else hide">
<sidebar1-cmp></sidebar1-cmp>
<ng-template #hide>
<Sidebar2-cmp></sidebar2-cmp>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

Simply
If()
{ Shows sidebar1}
Else
{shows sidebar2}

I do not know,how do use this reference variable(#show,#hide) in child components(sidebar1,sidebar2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use "\*ngIf else"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-can-i-use-ngif-else)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `*ngIf` to sidebar1 component tag, like the following:

```
<div>
  <sidebar1-cmp *ngIf="show; else hide"></sidebar1-cmp>
  <ng-template #hide>
    <Sidebar2-cmp></sidebar2-cmp>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay.thank you @ mateus schneiders one more doubt is how could i use show and hide in child components