# How to place condition while, looping form array in html

Tags: angular, formarray, recvfrom

I have a formarray in the form, Need to hide and show based on dropdown value - **is_dependent_exist**

I have tried like below:

```
var all_user_custom_fields = [
  {
    'field_name_slug': 'radio_button_with_group_custom_field8',
    'is_dependent_exist': 0
  },
  {
    'field_name_slug': 'radio_button_with_default_value',
    'is_dependent_exist': 1
  },
  {
    'field_name_slug': 'radio_button_with_mandatory',
    'is_dependent_exist': 1
  },
  {
    'field_name_slug': 'check_box_with_mandatory',
    'is_dependent_exist': 0
  }
];
<div  *ngFor="let CustomUser of custom_field_dataArray.controls; index as c;" [formGroupName]="c" class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4  
*ngIf="all_user_custom_fields[c]?.is_dependent_exist != 1">
<input formControlName="{{all_user_custom_fields[c]?.field_name_slug}}" type="text" (keyup)="validate($event, c, all_user_custom_fields[c]?.field_name_slug)" pInputText />
</div>
```

Getting issue like
Property 'c' does not exist on type 'UsersComponent'.

I need to display only is_dependent_exist = 0 value fields

Comment: Thank you Ghaith Arfaoui, But it's not working for me, Again getting Property 'c' does not exist on type

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the index variable c within the *ngIf condition, but Angular is complaining because it doesn't recognize the property 'c' on the component class. Instead, you should use the index variable directly without the 'c' property. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<div *ngFor="let CustomUser of custom_field_dataArray.controls; index as c" class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4"
  [formGroupName]="c" *ngIf="all_user_custom_fields[c]?.is_dependent_exist !== 1">

  <!-- Your form fields go here -->

</div>
```

In this code snippet, I removed the unnecessary 'c' property from the *ngIf condition. Now, it should work as expected. This way, you are checking the is_dependent_exist property of the corresponding item in the all_user_custom_fields array based on the index directly.

Comment: Thank you Ghaith Arfaoui, But it's not working for me, Again getting Property 'c' does not exist on type

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 directives (`*ngFor` and `*ngIf`) on the same element.

This should work :

```
<div *ngFor="let CustomUser of custom_field_dataArray.controls; index as c;" [formGroupName]="c" class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4">
    <div *ngIf="all_user_custom_fields[c]?.is_dependent_exist != 1">
        <input formControlName="{{all_user_custom_fields[c]?.field_name_slug}}" type="text" (keyup)="validate($event, c, all_user_custom_fields[c]?.field_name_slug)" pInputText />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you don't want create extra "tag" replace one of the divs by [ng-content](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-element)

Comment: a note to OP, if you do go down this route, you can stick an `else` in the if statement to display some other content like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/43006550/7147233