# How do I use ng-if to display or hide input fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Quite new to angular JS and need some help. How do I use **ng-if** to display or hide different input fields? I'm currently using **ng-show** but it doesn't completely remove the DOM, therefore making it difficult during validation. I want the input fields displaying within a specific div to become mandatory **ONLY** when selected.

When I click **Select Fund**, I want the showme2 div to display and the fields to become mandatory. When I click **Select Product**, I want the showme1 div to display and the fields to become mandatory. See my current code below:

```
<div ng-show="showme1">
         <div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Product details</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product1</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" id="productName1" required="required" placeholder="Product 1">
           </div>
        </div>

        <<div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Product details</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product2</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" id="productName2" required="required" placeholder="Product 2">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" align="center" ng-click="showme2=true; showme1=false"><a>(or Select Fund)</a><br /></div>
        </div>
</div>


<div ng-show="showme2">
         <div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Fund details</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product1</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="fundName" class="form-control" id="fundName1" required="required" placeholder="Fund 1">
           </div>
        </div>

        <<div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Product details</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product2</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="fundName" class="form-control" id="fundName2" required="required" placeholder="Fund 2">
           </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-click="showme1=true; showme2=false" align="center"><a>(or Select Product)</a></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what happens when you change `ng-show` to `ng-if`? They both expect a  boolean expression

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. How do I make ng-if work? Cheers.

Comment: That doesn't even answer the question asked. Need to be a lot more detailed if you want help here. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If it worked with ng-show before, it should "just work" if you replace the ng-show with ng-if. They both will display the element if the expression evaluates to true, the difference being ng-if removes it from the dom when it is not being displayed

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the feedback. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756818/1780122) stackoverflow answer to understand how ng-if is used.

> You can use **ng-if** to achieve **if(){..} else{..}** in Angular.js.
>
> ```
> <div ng-if="data.id == 5">
> <!-- If block -->
> </div>
> <div ng-if="data.id != 5">
> <!-- Your Else Block -->
> </div>
> ```

Additionally, I've modified your code snippet in a CodePen to use ng-if, see here. https://codepen.io/silicaRich/pen/PjwwPv

JS

```
var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);
```

HTML

```
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='TestApp'>

    <!-- Will display if showme == true -->
    <div ng-show="showme">
         <div class="form-group">
            <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Product details // showme1</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product1"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" id="productName1" required="required" placeholder="Product 1">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Product details // showme1</h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product2"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" id="productName2" required="required" placeholder="Product 2">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" align="center" ng-click="showme=false;"><a>(or Select Fund) // showme2</a><br /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Will display if showme == false -->
    <div ng-show="!showme">
         <div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Fund details // showme2 </h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product1"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="fundName" class="form-control" id="fundName1" required="required" placeholder="Fund 1">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <h3 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Add Fund details // showme2 </h3>
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="Product2"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="fundName" class="form-control" id="fundName2" required="required" placeholder="Fund 2">
           </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-click="showme=true;" align="center"><a>(or Select Product) // showme1</a></div>
        </div>
   </div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hope this helps.