# Angular - IF /ELSE condition in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have simple angular / html code where I have a table and on each `<li>` there is checkbox and some text

My code looks like:

```
            <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:statusFilter track by $index" ng-class="{completed: todo.completed}" ng-cloak>
                <div class="view">
                    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.completed" ng-click="changeStatus(task.id)">
                    <label ng-dblclick="editTodo(todo)">{{task.text}}</label>
                    <button class="destroy" ng-click="removeeTask(task)"></button>
                </div>
                <form ng-submit="doneEditing(todo)">
                    <input class="edit" ng-trim="false" ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="doneEditing(todo)" todo-escape="revertEditing(todo)" todo-focus="todo == editedTodo">
                </form>
            </li>
```

What this code do is:

1. When user click CHECKBOX it call ng-click and update "active" in
   database
2. Add "completed" which basicly change style of that `<li>` a bit

All data comes from some webservices and each task I have contains this information:

id

priority

text

active

My problem is that when I refresh the page I don't have any filter which add completed to all task which `active` is `0`

Can someone help me how to make some if / else condition for this purpose?

Comment: What are you trying to make conditional? just bind it to a variable on the scope or just use an inline ternary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if else statement in AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates)

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
ng-class="{{completed : todo.active == 0}}"
```

In this case li-Tag gets class completed if todo.active equals 0

Comment: Hey @David, thanks this actualy work really well.
But right now when I click checkbox nothing is going to happen :) becuase it is connected with todo.connected.

So is there some way how to maybe just press all checkbox on clicked ?

Comment: Where ist todo.connected coming from? Its not in the information you posted. Could you please explain more detail?