# Angular2 + nodejs(express) - how to check if session exists?

Tags: session, express, angular

My session create works well on server side but dependently of if the session exists, I would like to hide some elements printed in angular2 component template. How to check in angular2 component if the session created on server side already exists?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use token to validate communication sessions and then adjust the components of the template with conditions or other techniques.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810462/5125608

En español:
Podrías usar comunicación por token para validar las sesiones y posteriormente ajustar los componentes del template con condiciones u otras tecnicas.

vea https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810462/5125608