# AngularJS: Dynamically maintain the 3 states (InProgress,Success,Error) of a dropdown using ng-show/hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown to load the countries list by making an external api call. I want to show the three states of behavior(progress,success,error) in the dropdown using ng-show/hide. I am not sure how do i dynamically change ng-show/hide with in a dropdown like below?

1.**In Progress** (*loadCountry =='progress'* -Displaying the Loading... text)

2.**Binded Successfully**  (*loadCountry=='success'* -bind the api response of country's list)

3.**Error Message** (*loadCountry=='error'* - If any error occured during the api data
    retrieval)

How do i insert the behavior for in progress and error in the below bootstrap dropdown using ng-show. I am setting the value for loadCountry scope variable from the directive's controller as progress,success,error automatically as per the flow goes.

```
<div ng-show="loadCountry== 'success'>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnCntry" 
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        {{selectedCountry}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnCntry">
     <li ng-repeat="country in countryList">
             <a>{{country.name}}</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-show="loadCountry=='...'" inside your dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnCntry">
    <div ng-show=" loadCountry == 'progress' ">Loading countries...</div>
    <div ng-show=" loadCountry == 'error' ">There was a error while load countries :(</div>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countryList">
        <a>{{country.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I don't put an ng-show inside the `<li>` tag because it don't show anything og the countryList is empty, but if you need to hide it (because their style makes it seem ugly), you can add `ng-show=" loadCountry == 'success' "` inside it.

Comment: I want loading ... text is my default and only the one text if it progress. how do i change it that switch between progress/success in the default selector code <a>{{country.name}}</a>. How do i handle progress and success on this default selection?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates
You want something like that?