# Angular setting $sce in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to display videos in iframe, but nothing gets displayed even though I am getting the right embed link for it. I have tried testing it by just displaying the link and the correct link gets displayed, and when I am hardcoding the same link for the iframe, videos gets displayed,  but nothing gets rendered in the iframe when I am having it like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="article in articles" class="item-light">
    <img ng-show="article.external_media.length == 0 || article.external_media.url == ''"  src="http://coop.app/imagecache/cover/{{article.cover_image}}">
    <iframe ng-show="article.external_media.length > 0 && article.external_media.url != ''" src="{{article.external_media[0].url}}"></iframe>
</ion-item>
```

**Update**

Since I need to inject $sce dependency I wonder how to apply it to all the possible links in my controller. How would that function look?

This is my controller:

```
.controller('FrontPageController', function($scope, ArticleService, $state) {
  ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
})
```

Comment: It's an `$sce` issue, you can't put as src an untrusted value so you should inject `$sce` and trust this particular as valid resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an iframe src attribute from a variable in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I need to inject $sce dependency I wonder how to apply it to all the possible links in my controller. How would that function look?

I'd recommend a filter for this.

```
.filter( 'safeUrl', [
    '$sce'
    function( $sce ){
        return function(url){
             //not sure which one you need here
             return $sce.trustAsUrl(url)
        }
    }
])
```

in your html

```
<iframe src="{{article.external_media[0].url | safeUrl}}">
```

I advocate filters over controller methods only in I like to keep my controllers very lightweight.  If something needs to be *interpreted*, I use a filter.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I get ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{article.external_media[0].url | safeUrl }}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

Comment: Try using `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` instead?  I haven't used $sce for iFrames so I don't know which is the proper method to use ergo my comment `//not sure which one you need here`