# angularJS 1.2 if expression in class

Tags: angularjs

```
<div r6-modal-dialog class="r6modal-dialog--medium">
```

I would like to add `if` statement in `class`

I know that I can do it so:

```
<div r6-modal-dialog ng-show="!data.selectedValue" class="r6modal-dialog--medium">
<div r6-modal-dialog ng-show="data.selectedValue" class="r6modal-dialog--small">
```

Is it possible to do it in one line?

Comment: Have you tried: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I thick this link can help you [if else statement in AngularJS templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wit `ngCLass`

```
<div r6-modal-dialog ng-class="data.selectedValue? 'r6modal-dialog--small' : 'r6modal-dialog--medium'">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div r6-modal-dialog ng-class="{'r6modal-dialog--small': data.selectedValue, 
                      'r6modal-dialog--medium': !data.selectedValue}">
```

Comment: question is what is more readable. I prefer ternary operator notation :D

Comment: object syntax more flexible when we have multiple conditions and multiple classes to apply