# If statement in ionic, angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code in my controller on ionic app

```
// Shows test score to the user
alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: user + message,
    template: 'Your score: ' + testScore + '%',
    okText: Paid ? 'View test results' : 'Close'
});
```

i need to add an if where the message change if testScore var is > 50.
But i'm a beginner in ionic or angular js... Can any good guy give me help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your template:

```
var template = '<div>Your score: ' + testScore +'%</div>';
if (testScore > 50) {
    template += "<div>This only shows if testScore is higher than 50</div>";
}

alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: user + message,
    template: template,
    okText: Paid ? 'View test results' : 'Close'
});
```

Or, probably even better, handle it in the template in angular's way:

```
alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: user + message,
    scope: $scope, // the $scope object with the testScore property
    template: '<div>\
                   Your score: {{ testScore }}%>\
               </div>\
               <div ng-if="testScore > 50">\
                   This only shows if testScore is higher than 50\
               </div>',
    okText: Paid ? 'View test results' : 'Close'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do  like this

```
{{ConditionVar ? 'varIsTrue' : 'varIsFalse'}}
```

your example:

```
<div ng-if="testScore < 50">
    <!-- code to render a large video block-->
</div>
<div ng-if="testScore > 50">
    <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
</div>
```

more examples from here :

[if else statement in AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates)