# how to compare match angular expressions with a specific word

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, expression

I have 3 document-types.

- document
- folder
- documentplace

if the expression is `{{documenttype}}` = document, than create a document-icon.
if the expression is `{{documenttype}}` = folder than create a folder icon.
if the expression is `{{documenttype}}` = documentplace than create a adress icon.

I know excactly to do this in php, but in angular im a little bit over asked.

Comment: try this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) to do the trick. It will evaluates the expression in `on`, and display a `div` according to the value:

```
<div ng-switch on="documenttype">

    <div ng-switch-when="document">
        <img src="document.png"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="folder">
        <img src="folder.png"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="documentplace">
        <img src="documentplace.png"/>
    </div>

</div>
```