# AngularJS ng-if Ternary Conditional Attribute Use

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, user-interface

Lets assume below sudo code, As you professionals can see I want to use Ternary kind of condition with `ng-if` to apply different HTML `title` attribute.
I tried it as below but it did not work

```
<td>
     <span ng-if="isOk == true ? title ="Is Ok" : title ="Is Not Ok"></span>
</td>
```

I know I can achieve what I want applying `ng-if` in `<td>` level using below code

```
<td ng-if="isOk == true">
      <span title ="Is Ok"></span>
</td>
<td ng-if="isOk != true">
      <span title ="Is Not Ok"></span>
</td>
```

But I want to know weather I can use less code like Ternary check and achieve what I want with `ng-if`?

I thank you professionals in advace

Comment: I don't think it's possible with ngIf. As it specified on AngularJS website: "The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}." 

A better approach could be writing a new directive implementing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was specified in this thread: [if else statement in AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates), you can use ternary condition this way:

```
<span title="{{isOk ? 'Is Ok' : 'Is Not Ok'}}"></span>
```

Comment: then how can select different title attribute? @Jonathan

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have update the code. It should work. You can try also with ng-attr-title

Comment: Sorry Jonathan to ask u this question again, above code worked but what is instead of plain text like 'Is Ok' or 'Is Not Ok' we want to display text from angularJS model using {{text}} experssion?