# How to create a simple if then else in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginnner in angularjs, and I want to make an if statement to the following code.
Pseudocode:

```
if url.page exists then show this

 {{url.page | decodeURIComponent}}

else show 

{{url.path | decodeURIComponent}}
```

How can I achieve this?

This is my source code:

```
<a href="{{vm.company_website}}{{url.path}}"
   ng-if="url.path.indexOf('http') != 0"
   target="_blank"
   data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip" 
   data-original-title="{{url.path}}" style="color:rgb(98, 98, 98);"
>
   {{url.page | decodeURIComponent}}
</a>
```

Comment: This code is [tag:angularjs]. Please use the correct tags so people who can answer your question can also find it.

Comment: Are you intendedly using first version of angular, or would you like to use the most recent version?

Comment: @GCSDC yes, this is intentional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if else statement in AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{url.page ? url.page : url.path | decodeURIComponent}}` should do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use the ng-href directive, a sample use can be as:-

```
<div ng-init="myVar = undefined">
 <h1>Tutorials</h1>
 <a ng-href="{{myVar !== undefined ? myVar : 'http://sample.site.com'}}">Test</a>
</div>
```